# How to perform a filter on a json result using python

Tags: python-3.x

I have the json response below returned from an api call.

```
        { 
          "custAnalysis": [
            {
              "custPermId": "1234",
              "custType": "Business",
              "taxId": "8888",
              "custAddr": {
                "fullName": "Testing LIMITED",
                "addr1": "6734 APAPA RD"
              }
            },
            {
              "custPermId": "5678",
              "custType": "Business",
              "taxId": "9999",
              "custAddr": {
                "fullName": "SUPERMAN LLC",
                "addr1": "6734 APAPA RD"
              }
            },
            {
              "custPermId": "9234",
              "custType": "Business",
              "taxId": "8888",
              "custAddr": {
                "fullName": "DONALD LLC",
                "addr1": "6734 APAPA RD"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
```

I want to be able to search the json result above for a taxId of 8888. If taxId = 8888
return another json in the format below with the result

```
        {
          "custQueryResult": {
           "custPermId": 1234,
           "custPermId": 9234
          }
        }
```

I am very new to python. How can I achieve this in Python?

Answer (score 0):

```
search_texId=8888
search_result={"custQueryResult":[]}

for obj in response_dict["custAnalysis"]:
    if int(obj["taxId"])==search_texId:
        search_result["custQueryResult"].append({"custPermId": int(obj["custPermId"])})
print(search_result)
```

Dictionary couldn't assign the same name keys. So`custPermId` will be listed under `custQueryResult` key